# How do I write ajax endpoints for my vue app to grab data from database while allowing only my vue app to call them?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When a user changes a dropdown, I need to make an ajax call to an endpoint, that grabs the data and return it as a JSON.

I can do the event stuff with Vue, to make the request, but how do I guarantee that Vue is the requestor?

I can't really put an API key or something in the JS as that can be viewed through source. Someone could also watch the network tab in chrome and replay the requests to retrieve the data.

Comment: You cant. Max u can do some obfuscated client side generation of token, that will be verified on server. But if someone will have desire he still will bypass it

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to ask people to login first, there is *no* way you can do this. There is a HTTP header you can look for that most libraries add for Ajax requests, but that can be faked as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide any information from the request you are making. It's the server side on which you can make your code strong. To prevent fake request you can use CSRF token, you need to also validate if the user is logged in, you can check session etc. before you send the result to the client.